# Not able to build Xamarin Forms Project in Visual Studio 2017 RC

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I just installed Visual Studio 2017 RC to try out some of the new features like Xamarin Form Previewer. But i am not able to build the Xamarin Forms Project Created using the project template. Getting the below error.

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
>   File name: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView.dll'
>      at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
>      at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver, ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
>      at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver)   App1.Droid

Thank you in advance

Comment: I would suggest using the 'Report Problem' tool located at the top right of the VS2017 RC window. Turns out there are quite a few bugs there :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/2853/the-android-project-in-the-default-xamarin-forms-t.html

this worked for me too: in short remove all the nuget packages and reinstall Xamarin.Forms, it will reinstall the missing package too

Comment: Thank you @Luca. It worked for me. Thank you once again.